# Neo4j database schema recognition

Tags: graph, neo4j, graph-databases

I have Neo4j server with imported data from http://www.neo4j.org/develop/example_data Cineacts mvies and actors. I want to known the exact database schema, fileda relations etc. How can I do it? I already tried in webrowser tool but it did not helped.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also wrote a blog post about exploring a database:

http://jexp.de/blog/2014/02/exploring-an-unknown-neo4j-database/

And there is the neoprofiler by M. David Allen

https://github.com/moxious/neoprofiler

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at http://www.neo4j.org/graphgist?9c4cb9e842ed24a3feae which will help show you the structure of the graph